# I have an idea for a Stack Exchange site, but I don't have the time to get involved with site administration, how can I proceed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There could be a couple of reasons why someone could have an idea for a succesful Q&A site using Stack Exchange's platform, but can't get involved in the daily task of administrating the site.

For instance, they could have no skills related to web development or they just can't get involved because of their current job.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/ - No need to be a web developer or anything like that

Comment: Be prepared to put some time in, though; "just can't get involved" is not an option.  Area 51 is not really the place to say "I want a Q/A site about X" and then forget all about it.  If there aren't people committing and defining and using the site during the various phases of development, it will end up closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The steps for starting a new Stack Exchange site include:

- Propose the site topic on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- Define the site topic
- Gain commitment to the site by fellow users.

You can read the requirements for proposing, defining, commitment & launch process over at the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

You can see that there's no web dev/administration job involved, and that's very much by design. The idea is to gather support of Experts in the proposed topic, have them ask/answer while the Stack Exchange team makes use of the Stack Exchange engine in powering the site